# It gonna be and It is gonna be

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if both below sentences are correct and if indeed it is the case, what is the difference in meaning :

It gonna be...

It is gonna be...

Maybe once is for the present and the other one for the future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Gonna" is a shortening of "going to," and is a [colloquialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism). Since we're already using colloquial speech, the first example is understood to be the same as the second, but leaving out or eliding the "is" ("It is going to be" -> "It's gonna be" -> "It gonna be" -> all the same meanings). Since "gonna" is an alteration of "going to," all are future tense.

Answer (score 3):

"It gonna be" is colloquial, so it's accepted in spoken English (possibly) but not written English, not for publication or evaluation purposes anyway.
If you're asking about the difference between "it gonna be" and "it's gonna be" as it might be used in casual English, they are the same meaning.

I recommend avoiding "It gonna be" for writing unless you're quoting what somebody said. In a publication, it might even be clarified that this was specifically the grammar the speaker chose with a [sic]. For example:

When asked about the event, the man said "it gonna be [sic] lit".

The [sic] is used to indicate non-standard usage.